# Proving $\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{\alpha + 1}} \ dt$ diverges

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider $f(t)$, continuous on $[0,1]$, and $\alpha > 1$, and:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{\alpha + 1}} \ dt$$

How can we tell this integral diverges? Basically since $f$ is continuous it reaches it's minimum at $[0,1]$ so we could make a comparison with $\int_0^1 \frac{f(x_{min})}{t^{\alpha+1}}\ dt$, but $f$ isn't nessecarily non-negative.

Questions:
 1. Could look at $g(x) = f(x) + f(x_{min}) \ge 0$?
 2. Is there a more convinient way showing it diverges?

Thanks.

Comment: What if $f(t) = t^{\alpha+2}$?

Comment: Then it still diverges, but I get your point (it doesn't always diverge).

Comment: @jmiller How come with $\;f(t)=t^{\alpha+2}\;$ the integral "still diverges"??

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) I can't say. What does "more convenient" means here?

Comment: You right. I got confused. Of course it converges..

Comment: @Timbuc, for (2), it doesn't matter since the answer isn't always diverges. As you said, my assumption was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

$[0,1]$ interval is closed and bounded, hence - compact.

There's a theorem, according to which, any continuous function on a compact domain maps its domain into a compact set as well. Hence, $f(t)$ is bounded.

Now, if $f(t)$ is bounded:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{\alpha + 1}} dt > \int_0^1 \frac{f_{min}}{t^{\alpha + 1}} dt = f_{min} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^{\alpha + 1}} dt$$

The last integral here $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^{\alpha + 1}} dt$ diverges as $\alpha > 1$ and it being less than the original integral, makes the original integral diverge too.

Comment: but this thorem can be applied only for $f \ge 0$...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't recall that condition being necessary. Can you double-check it for me? If $f(t)$ is nonnegative for any $t$ in the domain interval and it's bounded, so will be $g(t) = f(t) - a$, where $a$ is a positive constant big enough to slide the infimum of $f(t)$ below zero.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the correct hypothesis is $\alpha >0$ (so that $\alpha+1>1$).

You just have to compute: if $\alpha \neq 0$, then
$$I_\varepsilon=\int_\varepsilon^1\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu t}{t^{\alpha+1}}=-\frac1\alpha\biggl(1-\frac 1{\varepsilon^\alpha}\biggr)$$
$I_\varepsilon$ has a limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$ if and only if $\alpha\le 0$. Thus here $I_\varepsilon\to+\infty\;$ when $\;\varepsilon\to 0$.